# how to enable Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated on .net framework 4.6?

Tags: c#, .net, vector

I am trying vector operations using System.Numerics with Visual Studio 2015 on my Haswell Core i7 desktop system. But `Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated` is returning false. My app is 64 bit.

Is there any setting to enable vector operations?

Comment: Maybe its `true` during the runtime (after JIT optimizations) and not when you are in debug.

Comment: I don't think this is something you can explicitly enable/disable, but rather an indicator of whether it's being hardware supported. I believe the main thing it needs is SIMD, which your CPU should definitely have. I think @ja72 is on the right track: have you tried release mode, too?

Comment: app crashes if I run the app from command line. Debug it works but IsHardwareAccelerated is false.

`Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: myapp.exe
  Application Version: 1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 55b93d41
  Fault Module Name: clr.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.6.81.0`

Comment: @RedFox just uncheck `prefer 32 bit` in project settings. It's better than forcing x64 imho

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to project properties -> Build.
Select platform target: x64
Check 'optimize code'.

Works fine on my Westmere I7-980x either in debug or release mode, when started w/o Debugging (CTRL+F5).

Comment: The key for me was the Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 5):

As Michal said, we need to build the project in x64 bit mode and RyuJIT will modifies this flag as IsHardwareAccelerated is 'JIT Intrinsic method'.

> IsHardwareAccelerated is what we refer to as a "JIT intrinsic method",
>   which means it is handled specially by the JIT. For this particular
>   circumstance, the key thing to note is that these "JIT intrinsics"
>   only turn on in release mode, so they will not be active during
>   debugging. They are also only active on RyuJIT compiling for x64.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2732#issuecomment-130142241